# Mixing boost mutexes with native threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, mutex, boost-thread

I have some code that uses native threads.  I'd like to modify a tiny fraction of it, but use some boost features.  In particular, I'd like to use boost::mutex::scoped_lock() and boost::condition's notify() and wait() functions.

Is there any issue using boost synchronization with non-boost threads?  In Windows?  In Linux redhat?  (I understand that underneath it is native threads, but want to ask just to be sure.)

thanks.

Comment: you should have a look at the `boost::thread` [configuration & limitations](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/thread/build.html) page and see how you may tune it to avoid specific issues that may arise with your app use of native threads.

Answer (score 0):

You could use most of the Boost.Thread synchronization interface.

Take a look at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.tutorial.native_from.